# How to pass javascript variable/object from one page to another?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to pass javascript object/ variable from page to another. so that i can use data for some fields, i want this values to be hidden and not visible while i my passing value from one page to another
I have already seen many examples of pass via http parameters, i dont want that and also session variables manage on server side, cause nothing has to be manage on sever side for that page.

i want to pass value as a hidden field or value to next page. how to pass it to new page when i open new page via

```
window.location="website/nextpage.jsp";
```

Also a note, i am beginner, so please sorry if the question seems to vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do not want to use session variables, cookies or local storage:

You can not "hide" a parameter so that your website user will not be able to see it.

If you submit data via a POST request - you can use hidden form elements.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="{YOUR PARAMETER}" />
```

If you use window.location - you will have to do it with a GET request

```
window.location="website/nextpage.jsp/param/{YOUR PARAMETER}";
```

Comment: thanx for your reply, can you tell me how to get these parameter on next page

Comment: @RakeshGarg Unfortunatly you can only process POST request on the server-side. So if you can only use HTML and Javascript - you will have to use the GET method. I guess there are many ways to extract the parameter values - to many to list them here in this comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can:

- Use hashes in the url by reading the [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties). Similar to GET requests, but does not need the server for passing. However, the parameters are visible in the url.
- Using [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie). Have JS "plant" the cookies on the previous page and read them on the receiving page.
- You could use [DOM storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) as well. Similar routine as cookies, plant and read.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about JSP specifically, but using a form with POST method hides data from (standard) users.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use html5's localStorage and sessionStorage for the purpose. for more help visit [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)